# Configuring Apache HTTP server with JBoss cartridge on Openshift

Tags: apache, tomcat, jboss, openshift, rules

I am using JBoss/Tomcat + Mysql cartridges.

I would like to serve static resources (css,js,images) using Apache and host those files outside the **WAR**.

I would also like to be able to use Apache to configure redirect rules etc.  Is there a way to do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not edit the vhost for your application, nor access the apache configs for your application when using one of the java cartridges.  An apache proxy sits in front of your application, but is not accessible by you.  You would either need to run a second gear with the php cartridge and host your static assets there, or try using a third party CDN to host your static files (such as amazon s3 or cloudfront).  But with just using one of the java cartridges on OpenShift Online, you can not configure it the way that you are trying to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as below. Put images, js & Css folder in Virtualhost document root. And call tomcat with help of mod_proxy_ajp configuration listed below.

```
ProxyPass /images !
ProxyPass /js !
ProxyPass /css !
ProxyPass           /       ajp://localhost:9009/
ProxyPassReverse    /       ajp://localhost:9009/
```

Comment: thanks, I probably wasn't clear enough.  I am aware how to do it but  I don't see where the apache config files are that I can edit, like httpd.conf etc.  I only installed mysql and jboss. Do I need to install a php cartridge for that? Thank you